# rsync doesn't want to sync any files (no errors)

Tags: ssh, rsync

For some reason rsync doesn't want to upload a directory with some of my local files (simple ones, like `test.txt`). I checked the permissions on both sides, all good, I set 777 everywhere.

Because it shows no errors it's very difficult to understand what's wrong.

```
$ rsync --archive --stats --human-readable -e "ssh myserver":~/dist/ src

Number of files: 9 (reg: 8, dir: 1)
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 6.08K bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 286
Total bytes received: 754

sent 286 bytes  received 754 bytes  2.08K bytes/sec
total size is 6.08K  speedup is 5.85
```

Also in my `~/.ssh/config` I have a pre-configured ssh access:

```
Host myserver
  Hostname xx.xx.xx:xx
  Port 1234
  User Admin
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myserver.pem
```

Comment: You're using the `-e` option wrong (or quoting wrong, or something). The argument after `-e` should be just the remote shell command, not the target computer and path (and if it's just "ssh", you can omit it because that's the default). Just use `...--human-readable myserver:~/dist/ src`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Wow, you are right! Maaan, THANK YOU! I've spent hours on this. Eventually my resulted command is: `rsync --archive --stats --human-readable src/ myserver:/dest/`. If you want you can wrap it into an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad it's working! I think it's better to just close this as a typo, since the main purpose of answered questions is as a search target to help other people with the same problem, and I think this one's probably unique.